# SQL, multiple outcomes is there a better way?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a webshop coded on php, but im stuck with a problem

I have tried multiple SQL queries but none of them work right now.

This is what I have

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE product_id = (SELECT product_id 
                    FROM `wishlist` 
                    WHERE user_id = :user_id)
```

Since the subquery outputs multiple product id's, it doesn't work properly.

Is there anyone around that knows?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `IN` or `= ANY`.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a IN clause or a join

IN

```
  SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id IN  (SELECT product_id FROM `wishlist` WHERE user_id = :user_id)
```

or a JOIN

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM products 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT product_id 
    FROM `wishlist` 
    WHERE user_id = :user_id
  ) t on t.product_id = products.product_id
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p
JOIN `wishlist` w
  ON p.product_id = w.product_id
WHERE w.user_id = :user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was using:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM `wishlist` WHERE user_id = :user_id)
```

thanks to @Gordon Linoff